# Jquery dialog won't open

Tags: jquery

what's wrong with my script. It should be open the dialog form, is it?

my html:

```
<section id="music_features">
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Your Playlist</h1>
                    <p>Up to only 3 files allowed for beta version</p>
                </hgroup>
            </header>
            <p id="song_upload_menu"><?php echo anchor('#', 'Upload Song');?></p>
            <article>
                <div id="song_upload_info">
                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>
                </div>
                <form id="song_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile/do_upload_song">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id_str;?>" />
                <label for="title">Song Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="30" value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>"/><br />
                <label for="album"> Album Title </label>
                <input type="text" name="album" id="album" size="30" value="<?php echo set_value('album'); ?>"/><br />
                <label for="artist">Artist</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('artist'); ?>"/><br />
                <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /><br />
                <input type="radio" name="license" id="license" value="owner"/>I AM the artist/owner of this song and I have the right for distribution<br />
                <input type="radio" name="license" id="license" value="not owner"/>I AM NOT the artist/owner of this song BUT I have the right for distribution</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="song_license_agreement"/>By selecting this option, I swear that all information entered is right<br />
                <!-- <input type="submit" id="song_upload_submit" value="Upload Your Song"/>-->
                <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
                </form>
            </article>
            <ul id="playlist">

            </ul>
        </section>
```

My .js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
refresh_song_list();

    //upload song dialog
    $('#music_features article').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons:{
                        'upload': function(){
                        $('#song_upload_form').attr('target', $('#upload_target').attr('id'));
                        $('#song_upload_form').submit();

                    }
            },
            close: function(){
                refresh_song_list();
            }
        });      


    $('#song_upload_menu').click(function(e){                             
        $('#music_features article').dialog('open'); // this one won't work.. so strange...   
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

when someone click the `#song_upload_menu` link the .js should open up the dialog right? but it won't. I've tried to execute this code into my js console : `$('#music_features article').dialog('open');` and it only return this `[]`

Could anyone here tell me what's wrong with my code?

UPDATE:
I issued this command into the console : `$('#music_features');` to find out something. I found that THERE IS NO such `<article>` element in the music_features section. 
Then i removed the folowing line of code from my .js :

```
$('#music_features article').dialog({  ...  });
```

after that I issued the same `$('#music_features');` command into the console and it returned that THERE IS an `<article>` element in my DOM and it is resides exactly inside the music_features. WHOAAAAAAA. how could it be???

Comment: do you include the jquery ui libary in your html page ?

Comment: @EvilP off course. This is so strange. Last time I run the script, it was working fine. Until I close the dialog (without submitting it), then I reloaded the page then the #song_upload_menu link doesn't work anymore... :-(

Comment: are there any errors on the firebug console

Comment: @3nigma nope. but when type this in firebug : `$('#music_features article').dialog('open');` it returns this `[]`

Comment: @under5hell what happens if you type `$('#music_features article')` in the console does it selects the desired element

Comment: @3nigma It should select the element. But It didn't. I even open up the source from browser, and the <article> element is there. This is really out of control :-( . Maybe this sounds silly, but I'll restart my computer. I'll let you know if there's something happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to select the article tag. Can you add the unique id to article and use the same for invoking the jquery dialog ?

1. `$('#articleDialog').dialog({` ... to call the Article dialog'
2. `$('#articleDialog').dialog('open');` to call the dialogbox
3. Update the article tag with id as `<article id="articleDialog">`

Comment: whoaa... cool.. it's working! great simple solution. Thanks! PS: but I still wondering why `$('#music_features article')` is not able to selected the `<article>` wheres it meets the jquery rule of thumb in selecting element. :-?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an element with id "music_features article" in your DOM.

You have to update the id in the dom for the element you want to show in a dialog or fix the correct id in your js code.

Comment: I think i have one. the most outer element is a section element with an ID = "music_features". Then inside it there is an article alement. So, It should get selected if I called it with $('#music features article') . CMIIW