# jQuery dialog won't open at the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a dialog with jQueryUI, but actually when I'm clicking on a link to open it, it generate some divs, and if I'm clicking a second time, the dialog appears.

EDIT : The "click" is an HyperLink that call a JS method (that handle my code), generated by a webobject (Apple WebObjects)

I'd like to open the dialog at the first click.

Here are the differents codes :

HTML before first click:

```
<div id="theDialog">Hello</div>
```

HTML after the first click:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="theDialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
        <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close">
        <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="theDialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
$("#theDialog").dialog().dialog('open');
```

This script gives me an error by the way (Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ,)

I've tried many possibilities before this script, like this post ([Jquery dialog won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971035/jquery-dialog-wont-open)) but actually I've always the same problem or an error in the console...

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700495/jquery-ui-dialog-not-opening-a-second-time), definitely you will get your issue resolved.

Comment: @kk4You Thanks, your link helps me a lot !

Comment: great. glad to know that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#theDialog").dialog().dialog('open');
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
$("#theDialog").dialog('open');
```

I would make a function out of this:

```
$("#theDialog").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#theDialog").dialog(opt).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering !
I tried, but I got an other error : 
cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post, I've a hyperlink that call the script to execute it

Answer (score 0):

First of all You should priovide more code so we can help You. The code You provided is not reproducable example depends on what You said :"Dialog open on second click" - i don't see any click function or evethandler.

I dont know dialog('open') function but this div with You try to open is display:none
So to display whole div just use jquery show().

Next thing is that You dont have any element that You can click and action to it. I renamed Your id "theDialog" to "theDialogButton". Next is to use this as a button and in jquery use click() function on this element.

```js
$('#theDialogButton').click(()=>
  $("#dialog").show()
  );
```

```css
body {
  background: white; /* try type yellow */
  color: #323232;

  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header"></h1>
<div id="theDialogButton">>Click to open <</div>

<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="dialog" style="display: none;" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="theDialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
        <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close">
        <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button>
    </div>
    <div id="theDialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't give enough information...
I'll edit my post, thanks for answering !